# GCP Service Account access issue to a pub/sub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, service-accounts, stackdriver

My current setup in GCP includes a Logging Sink to a Pub/Sub topic which is exporting certain Healthcare API log entries to a third party logging tools. Despite having, what I believe to be, all required permissions, the activity page shows Stackdriver config error with an error message something like this

```
Access to the topic was denied
The specified topic does not allow the service account associated with the log sink to publish to it. Grant publish permission for the service account specified in the sink's writerIdentity field on the topic.
```

Now the service account in question has the following set of permissions already assigned to it

```
Healthcare Dataset Administrator
Healthcare FHIR Resource Editor
Healthcare FHIR Resource Reader
Healthcare FHIR Store Administrator
Service Account Admin
Service Account Key Admin
Service Account User
Workload Identity User
Logs Configuration Writer
Logs Writer
Pub/Sub Editor
Pub/Sub Publisher
```

According to **[this thread](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/4735)**, its is a known issue but its already been past the 24 hour threshold mentioned in there so I am a bit confused.

Are there any particular permissions that I am missing here? I have tried recreating the sink once or twice to no use. Appreciate any help from the community on this one. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Here is what I found on running `gcloud logging sinks describe <sink name>`

```
createTime: '2021-02-23T00:42:35.363983703Z'
destination: <PUBSUB_TOPIC>
filter: resource.labels.service="healthcare.googleapis.com"
name: <SINK_NAME>
updateTime: '2021-03-01T18:44:50.694055502Z'
writerIdentity: <SA_NAME>
```

Comment: Can you share your sink configuration? `gcloud logging sinks describe <sink name>`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere couldn't find anything interesting there, editted the question with my findings

Comment: Is the SA_NAME of the writer identity is well granted on the PubSub topic? What are the organisation policies enforced on your organization?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I created the sink with terraform and set the `unique_writer_identity = true` initially, laster I also tried it with `unique_writer_identity = false`

Comment: When set to `true`, it created a unique SA `serviceAccount:cloud-logs@system.gserviceaccount.com`, which does not exactly show up in the Service Accounts section on the console. One more thing I noticed, the API calls are not logged for some reason, only what look like audit logs are published in the console. Would that be connected in some way?

Comment: I tried replicating the issue but I wasn’t able to do so; as soon as I created the Pub/Sub log sink and granted publishing permissions to the associated service account, as shown in the [documentation examples](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging#examples_4); logs started being published in the topic. The service account not appearing in the console is an expected behavior; this service account is automatically created and managed by GCP when you create a log sink so it doesn’t appear there, but you can still grant/remove its permissions via gcloud.

Comment: Could you verify the following details?

1. Not a single log has been published to the topic?
2. Have you double-checked that your service account has been granted Pub/Sub permissions over the specific Topic that you created for your sink?
3. Could you try creating the Pub/Sub sink and grant permissions to the service account without using Terraform and just using gcloud as mentioned in the example link above? That could help discard any issues on Terraform side or its configuration.(for testing purposes, make sure to omit the --log-filter parameter so no filter is applied to the log sink)

Comment: 4. API calls not being logged could be an entirely different issue, so I would recommend first verifying that your Pub/Sub sink is able to successfully publish logs and then moving onto that issue, possibly on a separate question.